# Fired too many times, how do I handle?

Tags: termination

I've had many jobs throughout my life and most of them I have been fired . How do I write my resume? Do I include all those jobs? And if I get called for an interview, do I tell the truth? There's no good explanation to the situations, but Im ready to do well . If given the chance...

Comment: Could you (discreetly) describe why you've been fired so frequently? Is it something that is acceptable (by Western mores and folkways) such as layoffs due to rough times for the company, or disagreements with managers on product direction; or was it things that are not acceptable, like drinking on the job, punching your boss or sleeping with his wife, substance abuse, etc?

Comment: I'm leaving this open.  This is not a duplicate, this is for multiple firings, and I'm curious as to what answers could help this person.

Comment: A bit more information:  Have you been fired for insubordination?  Fighting on the job? Stealing?  Drugs? Tardiness?   Give us some idea because the help we can give depends on the details.

Comment: Also, is there a consistent pattern to the firings? If so, it may be possible to fix the problem that is causing them, and then convince a potential employer it is fixed.

Comment: @DevNull It's not common in Western culture to want to get fired. When someone is laid off, they don't say they were "fired" but actually laid off. Being laid off is common in Western culture and not a big deal. Being fire is, and in any other culture I'd imagine.

Comment: Voting to re-open: the suggested duplicates do not cover the same scope. While much of the advice may be the same, I see this as a distinct question

Comment: @Dan I realize that. I'm trying to understand what OP means by "fired" to make sure he/she isn't using it in place of being dismissed for other reasons or without cause.

Comment: Looks like you have already had a lot of chances, time for a career change I would think.

Comment: What are all of the reasons you were fired?

Comment: Im not looking for insulting answers . if you can't help me, please do not waste my time by reading your comment . Like I said , there were no good reasons for me being fired ... It was mainly because I called out too much , one job my register was over and short too many times (never stole, never had any fights, never did drugs) I was young and simply didn't like responsibility . No matter what way I put it in , it doesnt sound good . My only question is do I put those jobs on my resume? Because I only have one job that is not a termination

Answer (score 9):

You definitely have an uphill battle.

On your resume, include the relevant work experience, the dates you worked there, and the work you did/achievements you had. Just like any other job.

During an interview you *should* be asked about why you left those jobs. **Absolutely tell the truth.** You will have to explain it. If you don't explain it satisfactorily, you will not be hired.

***The key here is to understand why you were fired. What did you do? What could/should you have done to avoid it? What have you already done to improve? What else are you going to do moving forward?***

Until you can answer those questions, you, honestly, shouldn't be hired.

You have to take full responsibility. You should not try and blame managers, former co-workers, unfair policies, etc. I would never hire someone who had been fired from multiple jobs without taking ownership and responsibility for it. We all make mistakes, but if you don't prove that you've learned from those mistakes, why in the world would a manager expect that you're done making them?

Comment: That doesn't answer my question . maybe you should re read it .

Comment: "How do I write my resume? Do I include all those jobs?" See 2nd sentence, starting with "On your resume...". "And if I get called for an interview, do I tell the truth?" See the bold sentence in the 3rd paragraph (**Absolutely tell the truth**). If you have more/specific questions, edit your question to include them.

Answer (score 5):

> If given the chance...

**Every time you get a job you're being given a chance.**

It's up to you to make the most of that chance.

> I've had many jobs throughout my life and most of them I have been fired

That's the first thing to work on.

Is it possible that you're applying for jobs that don't fit you very well?

- Some people want very quiet work with little responsibility, others want to make all the decisions and run the whole show.
- Some people want to work with their hands, others plonk away at keyboards
- Some people want a steady paycheck, others want to set their own hours
- ... and so on

Comment: I friend of mine was fired a lot of times too. Her problem? she is unable to follow orders if a manager tell her to do something she doesnt like she wont do it. She is only 21 so I expect her to learn. Maybe op share this problem of just being young.

Comment: @kifli I don't see how insubordination is a symptom of being "young", none of my friends or coworkers were like that at that age. It's just a character flaw.

Comment: Understood, I get that , but can you answer my question?